# Ход ладьи в шахматах на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть шахматное поле, допустим массив 100 элементов, если представить в виде квадрата получится следующие

```
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 0 3 0 0 5 0 0 0 9
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 9
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

цифрой 5 обозначено положение ладьи на поле, ходить она может по вертикали и горизонтали (для тех кто не играет в шахматы). Помогите написать алгоритм для поиска доступных ходов, следует учесть что на её пути может попасться чужая фигура - обозначена цифрой 3 на поле, тогда клетка с фигурой доступна для удара, либо своя фигура - цифра 2. Мучаюсь больше 2 часов, кроме тупого перебора по очереди четырех направлений ни че в голову не лезет (

Comment: А тут в любом случае задача сведется к перебору).

Comment: Ну это само собой, просто у меня получался "не красивый" перебор :) хочется увидеть варианты других людей

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = f.x, y = f.y; // сохраняем координаты  
while(table[--x][y] == 0)  
{  
    // помечаем клетку для прохода  
    if(table[x][y] <= 9) // своя фигура или край доски; отдельная проверка для черных/белых фигур  
    {  
        // снимаем отметку  
    }  
}  
//и по аналогии для ++x, --y и ++y
```

Думаю, как-то так.

Comment: Сейчас как то так сделано, хочется более изящно :) но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что надо попробовать замутить что-то вроде такого: ладья может ходить до края доски или до фигуры. Если нет фигур на пути ладьи - возможные ходы тупо вычисляются исходя из положения самой ладьи. Поэтому оптимальнее сделать нечто вроде пары хэшей, где ключ - это положение (например, сначала номер вертикали или номер горизнтали), а значение по ключу - это фигура (плюс её полное положение на доске). Таким образом, имея положение ладьи ты можешь посмотреть есть ли что-то на той же горизонтали/вертикали и если нет - ладья ходит, как говорится, от края до края =)) ; если есть, то до ближайшей фигуры и возможные ходы легко считаются по положению собственно ладьи и той фигуры, которая на пути. Хэши составляются перед началом партии и с каждым ходом обновляются.
Так, вроде чуть оптимальнее. =)

И, да, я люблю играть в шахматы. =)